# How to recolor GridView item

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I've got GridView which is kind of caledar like - it represents 31 day challenge. After you complete the challenge of the day, the background color of corresponding GridView item is set to green, works fine but I can't find a way to remove the background color let's say upon challenge reset..

```
private void showDone(boolean reset) {
    gridView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new 
    ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if(!reset)
                gridView.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            else
                gridView.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particular item in gridview can be colored via code like this:

```
gridView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
           gridView.getChildAt(POSITION).setBackgroundColor(Color.XXX);
        }
    });
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```